# Solve the following DE $\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{-y\left(x^2+y^2-1\right)}{x\left(x^2+y^2+1\right)}$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Can someone solve the following DE without using methods of  "exact differential equations" (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exact_differential_equation)? I can solve it using exact DE methods but not with homogenous DE or linear DE methods:
$$\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{-y\left(x^2+y^2-1\right)}{x\left(x^2+y^2+1\right)}.$$

Comment: How did you solve it using exact DE methods?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can (sort of). Step one: switch to polar coordinates, thinking of $r=r(\theta):$
\begin{align*}
r^2&=x^2+y^2\\
\theta&=\arctan(y/x)\\
x&=r\cos(\theta)\\
y&=r\sin(\theta).
\end{align*}
This was inspired by the $x^2+y^2$ in both numerator and denominator. Then we have
\begin{align*}
dy&=\sin(\theta)\,dr+r\cos(\theta)\,d\theta\\
dx&=\cos(\theta)\,dr-r\sin(\theta)\,d\theta,
\end{align*}
so the DE becomes
$$\frac{\sin(\theta)\,dr+r\cos(\theta)\,d\theta}{\cos(\theta)\,dr-r\sin(\theta)\,d\theta}=-\frac{r^2-1}{r^2+1}\,\tan(\theta),$$
which can be manipulated down to
\begin{align*}
r'r\sin(2\theta)+r^2\cos(2\theta)+1&=0\\
\frac{d}{d\theta}\left[r^2\sin(2\theta)\right]&=-2\\
r^2\sin(2\theta)&=-2\theta+C\\
r&=\pm\sqrt{(C-2\theta)\csc(2\theta)}.
\end{align*}
Then just substitute back using the substitutions above.

Now someone might complain that this step:
\begin{align*}
r'r\sin(2\theta)+r^2\cos(2\theta)+1&=0\\
\frac{d}{d\theta}\left[r^2\sin(2\theta)\right]&=-2,
\end{align*}
is using the machinery of exact differential equations because we had an "exact differential" or "exact derivative" on the LHS. At that point, I'm not sure I care. That this DE can be solved is the more important thing, since so many DEs (the vast majority, actually), cannot.

Comment: Can all the DE , which can be solved using exact DE method , be solved using other methods ? Coz i know that all DE (solvable  using other methods ) can be solved using exact DE ,is the reverse also true ? i.e is exact DE a superset or subset of other methods ? (hope u are able to understand)

Comment: Only certain kinds of DEs can be solved with certain methods of solution. The only thing I know to do is try one method. If it fails (and most methods fail, honestly), try another. I'm not aware of how much overlap there is among methods for certain DEs, though there certainly IS overlap.

Comment: Now someone might complain that this step:
r′rsin(2θ)+r2cos(2θ)+1ddθ[r2sin(2θ)]=0=−2 .                                                                         you can solve this using reducible to LDE

Comment: LDE is linear DE

Comment: Not seeing the linearity, unless you define a new variable $t=r^2.$ Might be linear in $t,$ then.

Comment: thats why i said REDUCIBLE to LDE

Answer (score 1):

$$\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{\left(-y\left(x^2+y^2-1\right)\right)}{\left(x\left(x^2+y^2+1\right)\right)} \tag 1$$
Change of variables :
$$\begin{cases}
p=xy\\
q=\frac{y}{x}
\end{cases}
\quad\implies\quad 
\begin{cases}
dp=y\:dx+x\:dy\\
dq=-\frac{y\:dx}{x^2}+\frac{dy}{x}
\end{cases}
\quad\text{and}\quad
\begin{cases}
y^2=p\:q\\
x^2=\frac{p}{q}
\end{cases} \tag 2
$$
With notations $\frac{dq}{dp}=q'$ and $\frac{dy}{dx}=y'$ :

$$q'=\frac{q\:(y'-q)}{p\:(y'+q)} \tag 3$$

From $(1)$ and $(2)$:
$$y'=\frac{\left(-y\left(x^2+y^2-1\right)\right)}{\left(x\left(x^2+y^2+1\right)\right)}=-t\frac{t^2p+p-1}{t^2p+p+1} \tag 4$$
Putting $(4)$ into $(3)$ and after simplification one get to :
$$q'=\frac{dq}{dp}=-q^2-1$$
This is a separable ODE which solution is :
$$p=\tan^{-1}(q)+C$$
The final result on the form of implicit equation is :
$$\boxed{x\:y-\tan^{-1}(\frac{y}{x})=C}$$

Comment: how does t come in the picture ?

Comment: $t= q$. Typo corrected.